# What should I wash my walls with prior to using "peel and stick" tiles except TSP?

Tags: kitchens, backsplash

I am installing peel and stick tiles as a backsplash.  I would like to know what to wash the walls with before installing.  The walls were painted eight years ago.

Answer (score 3):

Borax is a great substitute for TSP. Mixed with water, it is a very good degreaser. Just scrub your walls with it and let it dry completely. Any ammonia-based cleanser will also do the job. With peel and stick tiles read and follow all the manufacturer instructions accurately.